# Running Selenium tests programmatically in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, testng, integration-testing

I need to run Selenium tests programmatically which is written in testNG. I have already tried running TestNG programmatically by pointing to a jar as shown below.

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestJar(jarFilePath);
testng.setOutputDirectory("Results/TestNG/");
testng.run();
```

I want to run the Selenium test in headless mode and is that possible to do when running with TestNG? I cannot edit any test classes but rather run the provided jar in headless mode. So the above code is the only place to do changes. Is this possible and what other options can be used to run Selenium programmatically??

Comment: where are you initializing driver ?

Comment: WebDriver, if that answers your question.

Comment: @AsmaZinneeraJabir - When you say run in headless mode, what do you mean ? Headless mode is an attribute of the machine+browser and not an attribute of your testcase or TestNG for that matter. Ofcourse you can use Selenium to indicate that you need to run Firefox/Chrome in headless mode (if that's the case, you would need to show us your webdriver instantiation logic). But in general, if you run your tests from a unix box for which you have configured display via `xvfb` that should satisfy your usecase.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - My requirement is that I have a jar containing test classes + testng.xml. I am not able to see what the tests look like. I only want to execute them through testNG. But when I run it, it should run in CLI mode (which I mean as headless) since it should run on a server machine with no GUI.